# Using cte inside current table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create an expression, plase see example below.

```
with cte1  (ex1)
as
(
 select SUM(HasItems) 
 from InventoryTransTemp where HasItems !=0 
) 

select distinct TableName,ex1 from InventoryTransTemp  where Active=1
```

I'm getting error Invalid column name 'ex1'.
I want the sum from ex1 to be connected with the current table in select state and also to have where clause,as example active=1

#### More specific to sum all rows from each TableName which HasItems!=0

Comment: select ex1 = Sum(HasItems)
or if you prefer Select Sum(HasItems) as ex1; specify the column alias inside the CTE1 . Should not error out like that. And you can take it out from outside in the With clause line (ex1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-query then.

```
select distinct 
   TableName
   ,ex1 = (select SUM(HasItems) from InventoryTransTemp where HasItems !=0 )
from InventoryTransTemp  
where Active=1
```

If the tables are related, then you need to correlate the sub-query or simply join the tables.

```
select distinct 
   t.TableName
   ,ex1 = (select SUM(t2.HasItems) 
           from InventoryTransTemp t2 
           where t2.HasItems !=0 
                 and t1.somecolumn = t2.somecolumn)
from InventoryTransTemp t  
where t.Active=1
```

Comment: Thank you, with your example i have fully understand the process i need to use